# jQuery select every time first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

HTML:

```
<div class="vote" id="<?php echo $id; ?>">
```

jQuery:

```
$('.vote').on('click', function() {
    var div = $(".vote").attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "vote.php",
        data: {
            id: $(".vote").attr('id')
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert(div);
        }
    });
});
```

this works, **but** `div` var it's always first element - and runs twice (two divs with `vote` class).

I use AJAX for displaying results (divs with `vote` class) also.

Why is this happening and how can I fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `this`, which refers to element which invoked the element.

```
var div = $(this).attr('id'); //this.id;
```

When you are using `$(".vote").attr('id')` it will always return you id of first element.

As you are using `id` to store custom data. I would recommend you to use `data-*` prefixed custom attribute which can be fetched by using [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

```
<div class="vote" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>">
```

Then you can use

```
 var id = $(this).data('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use current elements clicked context `this`:

```
var div = this.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `this.id` instead of `$('.vote').attr('id')`, because javascript will get the first id he founds if you use `$('.vote').attr('id')`

Comment: There is nothing like `$(this).attr('id')` in OP's code!

Answer (score 0):

Replace your $('.vote') to $(this) like this below:

```
$('.vote').on('click', function() {
    var div = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "vote.php",
        data: {
            id: $(this).attr('id')
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert(div);
        }
    });
});
```